# Instalar e configurar a Pilha Lamp No Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Olá eu sou novo no linux, e gostaria de instalar um ambiente de desenvolvimento PHP e Laravel no meu ubuntu 16.04 para estudar tanto a linguagem como o framework, e para isso eu preciso do:

Apache
Mysql
PHP 7
Composer

Eu preciso do composer para instalar o Laravel, de preferência a versão mais nova, ou no mínimo a versão 5.2, pretendo usar o Atom como Editor e o Mysql Workbench como SGBD.

Nunca antes tive contato com Linux, gostaria de saber também como iniciar os servicos, se alguém puder ao menos me indicar um artigo sobre isso (pode ser em inglês) estaria grato.

Answer (score 1):

Atualizando o sistema:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Instalando o Apache:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Iniciando o apache:

```
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

Teste a instalação chamando `localhost` em um browser.

Instalando o MySQL:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server php7-mysql
```

Instalando o PHP7

```
$ sudo apt install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mbstring
```

Instalando o Composer (vc vai precisar do zip e do git):

```
$ sudo apt install zip 
$ apt install git
$ cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

O último comando deve criar um arquivo chamado compser.phar no seu diretório home, que poderá ser execudado na linha de comando, para instala-lo de forma global, mova-o para o diretorio `/usr/local/bin/`com o comando:

```
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Tente ver os comandos do composer:

```
$ composer
```

Instalando Lavarel, primeiro vamos configurar o mysql, faça login com a senha que vc informou no momento da instalação:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Apos fazer login, vc estará no prompt do `mysql`, digite os comandos (os nomes para `USER`. E `DATABSE`, podem ser diferentes do exemplo:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'laravel'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'laravel';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'laravel'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE DATABASE laravel;
```

Ok, tudo instalado, agora clone um projeto lavarel para testar, sugiro [esse do próprio lavarel.](https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-basic) O projeto tem, também, [um bom tutorial.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart)

**Observação final:**
Se voce tiver pressa e máquina para rodar uma virtual, talvez seja melhor instalar uma appliance, tem algumas **free** muito boas, por exemplo:

[Debian Bitnami.](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/virtual-machine)
Technologies:   MySQL, PHP, Varnish, Apache, phpMyAdmin, Smarty, Zend Framework, Laravel, CodeIgniter, Symfony, CakePHP

Instale no próprio sistema linux que vc está usando (ou no windows, se preferir) e, assim, vc tem tempo para ir instalando com calma na maquina real, isso se não acabar gostando da virtual e ficando com ela defintivamente. :-)